# SQL: Most Occurring Username for Email, ordered by most entries from Email

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a link to a very similar question, except in their example they only are concerned about one column, where I will be concerned about more than one.
[SQL Select most common values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853671/sql-select-most-common-values)

Here is my problem:

I need to display an email addr, number of comments that user has left, and display the most common username associated with each email. I have already taken care of the first two steps; i.e. I have it displaying email along with number of comments. Now the client wants the most common username.

here is the query to get the the email and count of comments I mentioned above.

```
select comment_author_email, count(*) from wp_comments group by comment_author_email order by count(*) desc
```

Now I have the task of getting the most common username to display in the third column.

For example:

```
email  |  username | comment
------------------------------
1@test | one       | blah..
1@test | ONE       | blah..
1@test | one       | blah..
2@test | TWO       | blah..
2@test | TWO       | blah..
3@test | tre       | blah..
```

I would expect as output

```
email   |numComments| mostCommonName
------------------------------------
1@test  | 3         | one
2@test  | 2         | TWO
3@test  | 1         | tre
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good place to use the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick. But this requires a subquery.

```
select comment_author_email, sum(cnt),
       substring_index(group_concat(username order by cnt desc), ',', 1) as MostCommonName
from (select comment_author_email, username, count(*) as cnt
      from wp_comments
      group by comment_author_email, username
     ) cu
group by comment_author_email
order by sum(cnt) desc;
```

Comment: ^ You @Gordon Linoff are a genius, and I thank you! :D Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do this. (It's easy to extract the most frequent username by applying `GROUP BY` on emails+usernames ordered by frequency):

```
select email, sum(n) numComments, username mostCommonName
from (
  select email, username, count(comment) n, count(username) u
  from wp_comments
  group by email, username
  order by u desc) a
group by email;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65b3a/7)