# Select most common value?

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table

I have to select the most common values in the columns of a table, and output it in a table, but I don't know how to do it (in a single query)

here is my table 'stats':

```
Page | Referrer | Useragent
__________________________
bla  | bla bla  | bla bla
```

My code:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>page</td><td>referrer</td><td>useragent</td></tr>";
$stmt = $db-prepare("SELECT `page`, COUNT(`page`) AS FREQ FROM  `stats` GROUP BY `page` ORDER BY FREQ DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
echo "<tr><td>{$result['page']}</td>";
// and so on with the other two columns
```

Is there a best way to do it?

**And if the query returns two values?**
 (there are two values in the column that appears exactly the same time, and both are the most frequent)

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question shows how to get one row, but there's a later answer that shows how to get all the rows with the most frequent value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853671/sql-select-most-common-values

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure this answers the question as I don't see how the linked answer handles ties.

Comment: [the third answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18029066/1491895) handles ties.